# LAMPP: Get Lampp to use the right php version for xdebug

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, lampp

I am trying for days now to get xdebug 2.5.1 running on my elementaryOS machine using php7. Finally, I found that two versions of PHP seem to installed and configured on my computer.

php -v leads to

```
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, 
by Zend Technologies
```

but running phpinfo() in my LAMPP does not display any occurrence of xdebug. So I assume that lampp is not correctly configured to work with the php version that has xdebug installed.

So what do I have to do?

Comment: You have to tell PHP's CLI version apart from the version integrated as module into the http server. They indeed are completely separate, so might well have different versions. They also have different configuration files...

Comment: `php -v` will prompt the cli sapi version , `phpinfo()` will show you your php http server version

Comment: OK, so what exactly do I need to do?

Comment: Check the `php -i` and `phpinfo()` output respectively -- check what config files it uses (will be in top header table) and edit corresponding files as needed.